# The difference between ‘in a good mood’ and ‘in a good spirits’?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between ‘in a good mood’ and ‘in a good spirits’?

I see those in the same book.

Comment: What book, or can you give specific quotes please?

Comment: @seventyeightist In the book, it is ‘in a good spirit’. It is a Chinese teaching book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In a good mood" and "in good spirits" (note: not in "A" good spirits which is incorrect) are basically the same. They both mean - being positive, upbeat, optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly **In a Good Spirits** would not work as a sentence, **Your using A Good as a non-plural phrase, then mixing in a plural phrase "Spirits"**, So it would be **In a Good Spirit.**

But yes they would work with a similar meaning, but Good Spirit usually represents when your up for something or your extreme liking of something, like when people say "I have lots of school spirit!" They mean they really like their school while Good Mood simply means your not sad, unhappy, mad, Etc.